# creating nuget package on local machine imported project ...Microsoft.WebApplication.targets... cannot be found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, msbuild, nuget

I'm trying to make a nuget package of an MVC 5 project, and i get the following error in the console.

```
C:\Projects>nuget pack WebApplication3\WebApplication3\WebApplication3.csproj
```

> Attempting to build package from 'WebApplication3.csproj'.  The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.  C:\Users\Michael\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WebApplication3\WebApplication3\WebApplication3.csproj

In the .csproj

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="false" />
```

I don't have VS 2010 installed on my machine.  Just VS2013.  What changes do i have to make in order for this to build and package?

Answer (score 3):

Landed on this thread and for anyone battling with this issue (who has Visual studio 2013 and also lands on this thread) and looking for a quick fix just copy this folder

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\WebApplications

to

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0

See these links for further detail:

[Link1](http://www.danmusk.com/how-to-build-asp-net-applications-in-teamcity-with-msbuild-tools-2013-and-net-framework-4-5-sdk/) with specific reference to heading/section "WebApplication.Targets"

[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7239418/the-imported-project-microsoft-webapplications-targets-was-not-found) with reference to Jim Lamb's answer.