# MSBuild Errors for Database Project on TFS server with VS 2013 shell

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools, sql-server-2014

Continuous Build Database Project fails when building on TFS server.  We have Visual Studio 2013 Shell (Integrated) installed.  There does not appear to be a way to install **SQL Server Data Tools 2013** thru' **Tools** > **Extensions and Updates...** menu.

The redacted error is below...

C:\TFSBuild\XXX\XXX\Database_CI\Sources\Database\XXX\XXX.sqlproj (126): The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

Has anyone experienced this?  Is there a solution or work-around?  Is SSDT available for VS 2013 Shell for SQL Server 2014?

Answer (score 4):

I have recently installed the Visual Studio Shell (Isolated) and (Integrated) on our build server and it does not include the SQL Server tooling components. I found out that SQL Server tooling is built in to the following versions of Visual Studio (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh297027)):

- Express for Web,
- Express for Windows Desktop,
- Professional,
- Premium, and
- Ultimate

I would recommend installing at least the Professional version and then you should get the SQL Server Data Tools components that are required for building.

SQL Server Tooling is now built into the above listed versions of Visual Studio 2013 ([SSDT and Visual Studio versions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2014/01/30/ssdt-and-visual-studio-versions.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:%20ssdtblog%20%28SQL%20Server%20Developer%20Tools%20Team%20Blog%29)) and the latest March update of Visual Studio 2013 now includes SQL Server 2014 support ([SQL Server Data Tools for SQL Server 2014 is available](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2014/03/25/sql-server-data-tools-for-sql-server-2014-is-available.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:%20ssdtblog%20%28SQL%20Server%20Developer%20Tools%20Team%20Blog%29).)

To force your build to use the correct version of MSBuild set the Process - Advanced - MSBuild arguments = "/p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0" (without the quotes) as shown.

[image: MSBuild arguments setting]

Comment: I did end up installing the full version of VS2013, and replaced SQL Server 2014 with 2012, after much frustration.  It now works well with all components.  I wish MS could have been more clear about compatibilities of different components, especially the latest releases.

Comment: @paulwebber10: yes that seems to be the easiest way to do it. This related topic describes and has links to how it can be done without Visual Studio installed, but it involves a lot of additional steps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15556339/how-to-build-sqlproj-projects-on-a-build-server?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You can download SSDT for VS2012 [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/jj650015) and that should get the database pre-reqs on your build server.

I do see mention of "Sql Server Tooling in Visual Studio 2013" on [this landing page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh297027), and I think it implies these tools should be available with the shell, so if you could, check to see if you have that targets file somewhere on your build server.

Go into C:\Program Files(x86)\ and do a "`dir Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets /s /b`" and see if something comes up.

Right now it's hard-coded to this location:
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets
You might want to see if the file already exists, but in another location, like in an "v12.0" folder instead of the "v11.0" subfolder.

**EDIT**
Actually, what's the value on line 126 of your .sqlproj?

If it says this:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets" />
```

Change it to read:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets" />
```

Then have everyone test it using diagnostic logging, then gather the logs and compare them to make sure that version is consistent so you can start phasing out the legacy bits.

Comment: It does read like you say above with $(VisualStudioVersion) and it is stated as 10.0.  I changed it 12.0, but it reverts it back to 11.0.  Also, I only have the directory search yielded only v12.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed it by downloading and installing the following

1. dacframework.msi
2. SQLDOM.MSI
3. SQLLS.MSI
4. SQLSysClrTypes.msi

from here:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=42295