# Error for MSBuild - Provides trouble every time I upload to Azure

Tags: visual-studio, azure, msbuild

his is how when I upload your site to my website, so give it problems: **MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets.14.0.0.3** It is the only time it makes mistakes that's when it will upload to my App service.

I've tried this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19826448/6576684

and download its here: http://www.nuget.org/packages/MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets/

I sit in visual studio 2015 and I have version number: 14.0.25420.01 Update 3

When it gives me error so doing the 10 attempt to create access it or how to explain it.

I also looked at the properties area and neither can I find nothing about it.

With that I looked at it here but is unsure of how to solve it ?: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2012/08/21/visual-studio-project-compatibility-and-visualstudioversion/

```
2>C:\Users\Jesper\Desktop\Sitename\packages\MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets.14.0.0.3\tools\VSToolsPath\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4276,5): Warning : Retrying the sync because a socket error (10054) occurred.  
2>Retrying operation 'Serialization' on object sitemanifest (sourcePath). Attempt 10 of 10.
 2>C:\Users\Jesper\Desktop\Sitename\packages\MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets.14.0.0.3\tools\VSToolsPath\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4276,5): Error : Web deployment task failed. (Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was tvangsafbrudt of a remote host.)
2>Publish failed to deploy.
```