# C# Build failed using MSbuild without Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net

Basically, I'm trying to build my project using MSbuild inside the .NET framework.

**NOTE: Visual Studio is not installed on the Windows server, however, all necessary .NET framework is installed.**

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild "D:\myCProject\WebApplication7.csproj" /p:Configuration=Debug;DeployOnBuild=True;PackageAsSingleFile=False;outdir=D:\myCProject\Publish
```

the above command is what I'm trying to run in the MSbuild.I'm getting then this error.

```
Build started 10/11/2017 12:47:13 PM.
Project "D:\myCProject\WebApplication7.csproj" on node 1 (default targets).
D:\myCProject\WebApplication7.csproj(212,3): error MSB4019: The imported projec
t "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\WebApplications\
Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <
Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
Done Building Project "D:\myCProject\WebApplication7.csproj" (default targets)
-- FAILED.


Build FAILED.

"D:\myCProject\WebApplication7.csproj" (default target) (1) ->
  D:\myCProject\WebApplication7.csproj(212,3): error MSB4019: The imported proj
ect "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\WebApplication
s\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the
 <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)
```

Any ideas?

**I need to build the project with MSBuild without Visual Studio without errors during the build.**

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980909/microsoft-webapplication-targets-was-not-found-on-the-build-server-whats-your) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17433904/v11-0-webapplications-microsoft-webapplication-targets-was-not-found-when-file-a)?

Comment: This is not duplicate question, the other problems were for projects using VS. my problem involves MSBuild without Visual Studio.

Comment: You're going to find you need VS. It's pretty much essential.

Comment: This is already answered in my first post but... 1. Solution: install MSBuild tools on build machine from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40760).
2. Solution: Copying the following folder from your dev machine to your build server fixes this if it's just web applications: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications. Second solution is to upgrade to VS 2015/2017 and to install MS Build Tools on build machine.