# Visual Studio 2013: Error when creating new web project

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2013

Whenever I create a new ASP Web project in Visual Studio 2013 I get the following error:

```
Error   1   The imported project "C:\Program Files 
(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets"
was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, 
and that the file exists on disk.
```

I know that by fixing it you go into the `csproj` file and comment out the line in which `<Import>` is on but I have to do that for every new project, is there another way I can fix this so that I don't get this error for new projects?

Comment: Can you create a file at that location, or even better copy the  correct file from another computer?

Comment: What edition and update level of VS2013 do you have?

Comment: I am running VS 2013 Ultimate. I did have VS2012 and 2010 installed but uninstalled them

Comment: I'm guessing you're targeting .NET 4 and when you uninstalled VS2010 it deleted the v10 targets. Do you get the error when creating webapps for .NET 4.5.1 in VS2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If didn't already install [Windows SDK for Windows 7](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279). Next follow [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3980909/147211).