# TFS build failing

Tags: .net, tfs

I am getting below error during build using TFS 2013.

I may need to change some environment variable value.

When I do build manually it works. but when I trigger it from build definition it through this error.

> The imported project
>   "...Path_on_windowsx86.....\Microsoft\VisualStudio***v11.0***\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets"
>   was not found.
>
> Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that
>   the file exists on disk.

Please advise.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980909/microsoft-webapplication-targets-was-not-found-on-the-build-server-whats-your

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have VS 2010 and 2013 both installed, After I tried it with VS 2010 it worked without any error. so issue was because of different version of TFS !!

Answer (score 1):

Your build server is missing the additional targets for the project that you are trying to build install visual studio on the build server and restart your build.