# Which parts of the Azure 2.7 SDK do I need to install on a build server?

Tags: .net, azure, msbuild, teamcity, build-server

Our build server is configured with just the [MS Build Tools 2015](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=48159) to ensure that we have just enough installed to build projects without having too much installed (i.e. full VS Developer Environment which has led to issues with deployments in the past).

We'd now like to start building Azure projects on this server but the options seem to be "Everything including an instance of Visual Studio", or "[All or some of these bits](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48178)":

- AzureMobileAppsSdkV1.0.msi
- AzureMobileAppsSdkV2.0.msi
- HiveODBC32.msi
- HiveODBC64.msi
- Microsoft.Azure.DataFactoryTools.msi
- Microsoft.Azure.HDInsightToolsForVS2013.msi
- Microsoft.Azure.HDInsightToolsForVS2015.msi
- MicrosoftAzureAuthoringTools-x64.msi
- MicrosoftAzureAuthoringTools-x86.msi
- MicrosoftAzureComputeEmulator-x64.exe
- MicrosoftAzureComputeEmulator-x86.exe
- MicrosoftAzureLibsForNet-x64.msi
- MicrosoftAzureLibsForNet-x86.msi
- MicrosoftAzureQuickstarts.msi
- MicrosoftAzureStorageEmulator.msi
- MicrosoftAzureStorageTools.msi
- MicrosoftAzureTools.VS120.exe
- MicrosoftAzureTools.VS140.exe
- WebToolsExtensionsVS14.msi
- WebToolsExtensionsVS2013.msi
- WebToolsExtensionsVWD14.msi
- WebToolsExtensionsVWD2013.msi

Clearly I probably don't need the emulators...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In addition to the MS Build Tools, doing the following allowed me to build Azure Cloud Service projects on a Team City Build Agent:

1. [Copy the `Web` and `WebApplications` targets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3980909/33051) from `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0` on a machine with Visual Studio installed.
2. Then from the [SDK download page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48178) install the following in the order defined in the Install Instructions:

   1. MicrosoftAzureAuthoringTools-x64.msi
   2. MicrosoftAzureLibsForNet-x64.msi
   3. MicrosoftAzureTools.VS.140

Then using the **MSBuild Version** "MS Build Tools 2015", **MSBuild ToolsVersion** "14.0" my Azure Cloud Service projects build and package nicely.