# Visual Studio Can't Create an MVC error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I finally managed to install the "Web section" in my Visual Studio 2015 Community... Still I get a strange error when I try to create an ASP.NET project

> The imported project "D:\Program
>   Files(86x)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets"
>   was not found. Confirm that the path in the `<Import>` declaration is
>   correct, and that the file exists on disk.
>   C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\ybzkspue.v5t\Temp\TestForMVC.csproj

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSyxz.png

Comment: Welcome to SO. avoid posting screenshots. copy the error message and include that in the  question. You wont get much help otherwise.

Comment: @Nkosi done :D... can I get some help now

Comment: @Nkosi any ideas how to fix this error?

Comment: It takes some time to read up on possible causes. You can also do some research yourself in searching for that error.

Comment: help me please....

Comment: After some searching check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980909/microsoft-webapplication-targets-was-not-found-on-the-build-server-whats-your the message actually tells you what to do. check to make sure that the stated folder exists.

Comment: @Nkosi so what should i exactly do?

Comment: @Nkosi can't i just reinstall the visual studio??

Comment: That would be my suggestion. Try the reinstall.

Comment: @Nkosi well we'll see what it happens haha... for a second time today

Comment: That path looks wrong; is your Visual Studio really installed on drive D:?

Comment: @DourHighArch yes why not ?:D