# Error in Running Web App On Mac Visual Studio

Tags: macos, azure-web-app-service, visual-studio-mac

I am new to Visual Studio. I have downloaded a web app from Azure Multi-tenant. But when I am trying to run the app, I receive the  following error message:

```
/Users/MySystem/Desktop/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-multitenant-openidconnect/TodoListWebApp/TodoListWebApp.csproj(3,3): Error MSB4019: The imported project "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.0/lib/mono/xbuild/Microsoft/VisualStudio/v15.0/WebApplications/Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk. (MSB4019)
```

I have already tried to modify .csproj file as given in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980909/microsoft-webapplication-targets-was-not-found-on-the-build-server-whats-your) but am unable to resolve the issue. Please note I am working on Mac Visual Studio.

Any idea or suggestions would be grateful.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it clears the doubt. You didn't show your gratefulness by leaving this question open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> active-directory-dotnet-webapp-multitenant-openidconnect/TodoListWebApp

By searching the project name on web, I found it is [a sample .NET 4.5 MVC web app](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-multitenant-openidconnect).

> I am working on Mac Visual Studio

Web Application in Visual Studio for Mac is based on .NET Core and It can't work with sln/csproj files. I suggest you create a new project on your Visual Studio for Mac and copy the files from the original project.

Since the .NET Version on Mac is .NET Core which is difference from the sample app(.NET 4.5). You also need to modify some code. For example, ASP.NET Core application doesn't contain Global.asax.

For more information of how to create a asp.net core app, link below is for your reference.

[Create an ASP.NET Core MVC app with Visual Studio Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app-xplat/)