# MSBUILD getting failed with error MSB4062

Tags: azure-devops, msbuild-task

Getting error while running build task in VSTS devops.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets(477,5): Error MSB4062: The "SqlModelResolutionTask" task could not be loaded from the assembly \Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\Dac\150\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Tasks.Sql.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\Dac\150\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Tasks.Sql.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.

Comment: See if this helps you
[Using MSBuild to build SSDT projects with VS2017 fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47440260/using-msbuild-to-build-ssdt-projects-with-vs2017-fails)

Comment: which version of ssdt are you using ?

Comment: @D.J. using SSDT2019

Comment: that version won't with vs2012

Comment: @D.J. Actually I am using VS 2017 i got error during build so i pass the build parameter as 2012 to msbuild

Comment: ok, what error do you get when you don't pass 2012 to msbuild

Comment: Getting same error by pointing v11.0 . But at the beginning of build getting warning 'Visual Studio version '15.0' not found.'

Comment: try using "vsbuild"-task instead of "msbuild"-task. the "v15 not found" error is a known issue and has been resolved in task 'vsbuild'. But if you get the exact same error anyway you should check your project-file, there might be v11 hardcoded in there

Comment: vsbuild also getting the same error. Earlier it was working fine. Now all the projects getting the same error.

Comment: have you updated either vs or ssdt ? if this worked earlier then something must have changed

Comment: No I didn't change anything, after getting error have updated the SSDT. This error occurring only when the DB project is added.

Answer (score 0):

Use

> /p:StyleCopEnabled=false for .netFramework with msbuild
>
> -p:StyleCopEnabled=false for dotnetcore with dotnet publish

Answer (score -1):

> MSBUILD getting failed with error MSB4062

According to the error messages and the comments you posted, it seems you are build the the project that developed by Visual Studio 2017, but build it with old Visual Studio on Azure Devops.

To resolve this issue, you can try to install the Visual Studio 2017 on your private agent.

Hope this helps.