# Build sqlproj on Azure DevOps

Tags: build, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, sqlproj

I'm trying to use Azure DevOps Pipelines to build my .NET Core 2.1 solution from GitHub.  It includes a SQL project that has a TargetFrameworkVersion of `v4.6.2`.  This project always fails to build.

```
Build FAILED.

/home/vsts/work/1/s/MySolution/MyDatabase/MyDatabase.sqlproj : warning NU1503: Skipping restore for project '/home/vsts/work/1/s/MySolution/MyDatabase/MyDatabase.sqlproj'. The project file may be invalid or missing targets required for restore. [/home/vsts/work/1/s/MySolution/MySolution.sln]
/home/vsts/work/1/s/MySolution/MyDatabase/MyDatabase.sqlproj(57,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.403/Microsoft/VisualStudio/v15.0/SSDT/Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
1 Warning(s)
1 Error(s)
```

How do I reference or include those targets for the build server?  It builds fine in VS2017.  I've spent more than a day hunting and cannot find any information on this problem.

Comment: What kind of build agent are you using? Windows or Linux? How do you build your solution, do you've some sample yaml code to show us?

Comment: Thanks, that comment alone showed me the answer!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks to [Herman Cordes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/249948/herman-cordes) for directing my investigation.

The problem was the selected build server.  SSDT is a Windows-only package, so I had to use a Windows VM instead of the default Ubuntu VM, and use the **VSBuild@1** task instead of **DotNetCoreCLI@2**.

**azure-pipelines.yml**

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'vs2017-win2016'

steps:
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'vsbuild $(buildConfiguration)'
  inputs:
    configuration: $(buildConfiguration)
```

EDIT: The **MSBuild@1** task also works.

Comment: I have been using the `VSBuild@1` on a `windows2019` agent and I am getting the exact same error

Answer (score 3):

**Here is a solution for linux build agent**
Easiest way to build DacPac file on a linux agent is done via [MSBuild.Sdk.SqlProj](https://github.com/rr-wfm/MSBuild.Sdk.SqlProj)
Go to your database project directory in parallel to .sqlproj file create a directory like `DB.Build` under it create `DB.Build.csproj` copy.pase the content as below

```xml
<Project Sdk="MSBuild.Sdk.SqlProj/1.1.0"> <!-- This will pull in the required tools and dependencies to build a .dacpac with .NET Core -->
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Include="..\src\DB\masterdata\**\*.sql" /> <!-- link in the new .csproj to the .sql scripts in your existing database project -->
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

After run you will see dacpac file appears under `DB.Build/bin/Release/netstandard2.0/DB.Build.dacpac`

Here's my build agent output (Ubuntu agent on Azure devops)

```sh
Starting: SQL DB build Release
==============================================================================
Task         : .NET Core
Description  : Build, test, package, or publish a dotnet application, or run a custom dotnet command
Version      : 2.187.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli
==============================================================================
Info: .NET Core SDK/runtime 2.2 and 3.0 are now End of Life(EOL) and have been removed from all hosted agents. If you're using these SDK/runtimes on hosted agents, kindly upgrade to newer versions which are not EOL, or else use UseDotNet task to install the required version.
/opt/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/dotnet build /home/vsts/work/1/s/src/RecommenderAPI.DB/RecommenderAPI.DB/RecommenderAPI.DB.Build/RecommenderAPI.DB.Build.csproj -dl:CentralLogger,"/home/vsts/work/_tasks/DotNetCoreCLI_5541a522-603c-47ad-91fc-a4b1d163081b/2.187.0/dotnet-build-helpers/Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll"*ForwardingLogger,"/home/vsts/work/_tasks/DotNetCoreCLI_5541a522-603c-47ad-91fc-a4b1d163081b/2.187.0/dotnet-build-helpers/Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll" --configuration Release /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation=/home/vsts/work/1/recommender-service-cicd/DacPac/
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.5.0+d4cbfca49 for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Restore completed in 51.72 ms for /home/vsts/work/1/s/src/RecommenderAPI.DB/RecommenderAPI.DB/RecommenderAPI.DB.Build/RecommenderAPI.DB.Build.csproj.
  Using package name RecommenderAPI.DB.Build and version 1.0.0
  Using SQL Server version Sql150
  Deleting existing file /home/vsts/work/1/s/src/RecommenderAPI.DB/RecommenderAPI.DB/RecommenderAPI.DB.Build/obj/Release/netstandard2.0/RecommenderAPI.DB.Build.dacpac
  Writing model to /home/vsts/work/1/s/src/RecommenderAPI.DB/RecommenderAPI.DB/RecommenderAPI.DB.Build/obj/Release/netstandard2.0/RecommenderAPI.DB.Build.dacpac
  RecommenderAPI.DB.Build -> /home/vsts/work/1/s/src/RecommenderAPI.DB/RecommenderAPI.DB/RecommenderAPI.DB.Build/bin/Release/netstandard2.0/RecommenderAPI.DB.Build.dacpac

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.71

Finishing: SQL DB build Release
```

> Note: Make sure to restore you NuGet packages in step prior to build

Your ADO pipeline manifest should look like this:

```yaml
...

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Restore SQL Project'
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: '**/*DB*/*.csproj'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: 'db-feed'

...


- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'SQL DB build $(buildConfiguration)'
  inputs:
    command: build
    projects: '**/*DB*/*.csproj'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation=$(Pipeline.Workspace)/$(pipelineArtifactName)/DacPac/'
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having the exact same issue building a SQL Server project on an Azure DevOps CI/CD pipeline. None of the pre-built build tasks would work for me!

I solved this by avoiding to add a SQL Server project to the solution.

I achieved this by using an [MSBuild SDK](https://github.com/jmezach/MSBuild.Sdk.SqlProj), capable of producing a SQL Server Data-Tier Application package (`.dacpac`) from the set of SQL scripts. By adding this second project to the solution, I managed to continue taking advantage of linking the project to a live database through SQL Server Object Explorer on Visual Studio. I gave a more detailed explanation about my implementation in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61292024/1198379).