# Publish WebAPI project

Tags: c#, publish, webapi

I am trying to publish a WebaPI project, but I am not able to see any target options. I am getting blank screen.

[image]

Comment: could you please add more info about the error message you are receiving ?  This is so small I couldn't figure what it says.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the *Web development build tools* are not installed on your machine. You can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44704273/15075007) how to install them. Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: I tried to install but it didn't help. I installed VS 2017 and that solved the issue for me :)